# ¿De esta manera tengo bien la formula de los numero primos ? (python)

Tags: python

Realice hasta el momento mi siguiente código en python para halla numero impares de 1 a 1 , por favor si a mi formula le falta algo cuando el numero ya sea exageradamente grande decirme o si esta bueno aqui dejo un pequeño aporte.

```
def primo(x=0):
    i = False
    while i == False:
        try:
            print("Recuerde que el numero debe ser entero, numero>2, para que funcione el programa :3")
            x=int(input("Ingrese el numero al que desea saber si es primo : "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Debe ser un dato entero :c")
        if x<=2:
            x = None
            print("Tu numero debe ser mayor que 2 ")
            break
        if x%2==0:
            x= None
            print("No es primo, Retonor  : \n",x)
            break
        elif x%2!=0 and x/x==1 and x/1==x:
            i = True        
            print("primo",x)       
    return i,print(i)
primo()
print(primo)
print("Gracias por usarme By: SEBAS")
```

Comment: Pues no. Tu función en realidad mira sólo si es impar, pero eso no es lo mismo que primo. Por ejemplo el 9 o el 15 son impares, pero no primos por ser divisibles por 3. Las condiciones x/x == 1 y x/1 == x sobran, pues son ciertas _para cualquier_ número, sea primo o no. La característica de un primo no es que sea divisible por sí mismo o por 1, sino que **sólo** es divisible por sí mismo y por 1. Tienes que comprobar que no tenga ningún otro divisor. Eso requiere un bucle. Por otro lado, yo separaría la parte que pide el dato de la parte que comprueba si es primo, en diferentes funciones.

Comment: También deberías evitar imprimir resultados desde la función. La función debería limitarse a retornar `True` (si es primo) o `False` (si no lo es). Y que sea el programa principal el que imprima los mensajes según el valor retornado. Otra cosa más, el `print(primo)` no tiene mucho sentido, pues `primo` es la función, no el resultado.

Comment: Añadiendo a lo ya correctamente comentado por abulafia, el 2 es primo y es par, tenlo en cuenta... Quitando el 2 (que es primo) y cualquier otro par (que no lo es), para el resto usando fuerza bruta solo tienes que usar un ciclo que itere sobre los impares desde 3 hasta x - 1 y compruebe si  x es divisible entre alguno, si cualquiera de ellos es divisor (resto 0) no es primo. Se puede hacer una optimización muy simple, en realidad basta con iterar sobre los impares entre 3 y raiz cuadrada de x.

Comment: Por cierto, cuando uses variables asociadas a boleanos como condición de un ciclo no hagas `while i == False:`, sino simplemente `while i:`, igualmente en condicionales no debes hacer `if i == True` o `if  i == False`, sino simplemente `if i` e `if not i` respectivamente. Por cierto, `return i,print(i)` hace que la función retorne una tupla en la que el primer elemento es el valor de `i` y el segundo el retorno de `print`, `None`, es decir, algo como `(True, None)` o `(False, None)`....

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto un código que hice ya un tiempo sobre los números primos, espero te sirva y lo puedas adaptar a tu código..  Saludos

```
# Autor: Israel Flores

print('Números Primos')
print('==============')
print('')

primos = []
noprimos = []

num1 = int(input('Ingresa el 1er número: '))
num2 = int(input('Ingresa el 2do número: '))

for i in range(num1, num2):
    if i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0 and i % 7 != 0:
        primos.append(i)
    elif i == 2 or i == 3 or i == 5 or i == 7:
        primos.append(i)
    else:
        noprimos.append(i)

print('')
print('Los Números Primos desde el ', num1, ' hasta el ', num2, ' son: ', primos)
print('')
print('NO son Números Primos : ', noprimos)
```

Comment: Este código solo funciona para encontrar primos en un rango <= 120 y falla a partir de 121. En ese caso sería mejor hacer una comparación iterada del resto de división hasta la mitad (o la raíz) del valor.

Comment: Gracias. Tienes razón, fue uno de los primeros códigos que experimenté cuando comencé con Python, para serte franco nunca probé el código con mas de 100 jejeje error de novato. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta función te dice si un número es primo o no, retorna `True` si lo es, de lo contrario `False`.
Si un numero es mayor que 3, hace el resto de división entera, a partir de 3 incrementando de 2 a dos, hasta la raíz cuadrada del número. Esto como forma de optimizar el código. También se podría ir probando de 1 en 1, pero no sería tan eficiente.

Te agregué además, un pedazo de código para llamar a la función.

```
def es_primo(n):
    if n == 2:
        primo = True
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        primo = False
    else:
        primo = True
        raizq = int(n ** (0.5)) # Raiz cuadrada
        for x in range(3, raizq+1, 2): # [3, 5, 7...]
            if n % x == 0:
                primo = False
                break
    return primo

# Programa principal con llamada a la función
n = input("Ingresa un numero: ")
if n.isdigit():
    if es_primo(int(n)):
        print("Es un numero primo")
    else:
        print("No es un numero primo")
else:
    print("Error, debes ingresar un numero entero positivo")
```

Posibles problemas: Considera "1" como número primo.